# Can I profile memory allocated in external dll in C# (e.g. with Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delphi, dll, bstr

Is there a way to profile memory allocated in an external DLL, in my case the [SysAllocString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysallocstring) function?

The DLL is compiled from Delphi and I have control over both the Delphi and C# code if instrumentation needs to be written.

In the overview of the [Visual Studio memory profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019) it says the Windows SDK has been annotated to emit ETW event data which is tracked by the profiler. However I've been unable to confidently confirm if the DLL's SysAllocString memory is tracked in it.

Comment: If you are calling a dll from c# using DllImport the memory has to be allocated either using the Windows Allocate method or in c# (not c++).  The problem is calling a method the local memory is placed on the execution stack.  When you return from the method the stack is no longer valid so you can't extract the data after the return.  So you have to allocate in c# in non managed memory space using IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

Comment: @jdweng In the DLL the memory is allocated with the SysAllocString function from the windows API. In the C# it is accessible and fine to use, so the marshalling is working fine. My question is more about what happens to the memory allocated by SysAllocString in the Delphi code, and if there is a way to profile the memory allocated by the DLL. Hope that's clearer.

Comment: In c# you use             Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);
            and Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(IntPtr);  So you can free the memory in c# when you are done with the memory.  Or you can call a method in the DLL to free the memory.

Comment: @jdweng You're misunderstanding the question. I know I can free the memory on the C# side, what I'm looking for is information regarding memory profiling a C# application which includes the memory allocated by an external unmanaged DLL. To find potential leaks.

Comment: I'm  not familiar with any of the tools that does memory profiling.